# How to get from Antwerp to Breskens by bus (or other transport) but not train?

Tags: public-transport, netherlands, belgium

I would like to get from Antwerp to Breskens to get the Ferry there.

Apparently its not far, but using google I have to either get 1 tram and 3 buses or go via middelburg - which I want to avoid.

Since this is a border region, and 80Km of disntance, I believe there may be medium distance buses not available on-line.

Is there a bus that connects Antwerp and Breskens? or other alternative by public transport. Any other ideas that dont involve hitch hiking?

Comment: Amusingly, if I try to find "Antwerpen to Breskens, via Brugge" on 9292.nl, it takes that train to Vlissingen and the ferry to Breskens... *then* it goes to Brugge by bus, and then back to Breskens!

Comment: Anyway there exists a direct train from Antwerpen to Brugge, and from there the bus to Breskens. If you want to avoid the train, I wouldn't be surprised if a tram and three buses is the best you can do.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any direct buses as they are not listed in the travel planners for either side. Most people who travel cross border regularly will go by car, also as cross border public transport is rather expensive.

Comment: You might want to [ride a bike](https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/Antwerpen,+Belgique/4511+Breskens,+Pays-Bas/@51.2596514,3.8256777,11z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c3f68ebfc3887d:0x3eaf448482a88ab8!2m2!1d4.4024643!2d51.2194475!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c49928b6a1c8ef:0x5542460dad47ea56!2m2!1d3.5558783!2d51.3945258!3e1): it's flat and it will take you a little less than taking the buses (4h) but more than the train and ferry (3h).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid Middelburg, you may travel like so by public transport:

1. Train from Antwerpen Centraal to Gent St Pieters
2. Train from Gent St Pieters to Knokke-Heist Duinbergen
3. Short walk from the Duinbergen train station to the De Lijn bus station (10 min)
4. Bus De Lijn 814 from Knokke-Heist to Breskens

This should take you around 3h30, so only 30 minutes more than through Middelburg.

Another, cheaper option is to take buses:

1. Bus Connexxion 19 from Antwerpen, Metrostation Halewijnlaan to Hulst, Busstation
2. Bus Connexxion 20, 660 from Hulst, Busstation to Terneuzen, Busstation WST
3. Bus Connexxion 1 from Terneuzen, Busstation WST to Oostburg, Watertoren
4. Bus Connexxion 42 from Oostburg, Watertoren to Breskens

You might also want to ride a bike: it's flat and it will take you a little less than taking the buses (about 4 hours).